# Iptables check script syntax

Tags: iptables

Is there any way to test/check the syntax of a iptables rules script without modifying the actual firewall config (I think adding and deleting each rule is not the best way...).

I know about the -C option but it doesn't check options like chains and it's a bit tricky with its return codes, because 1 doesn't always mean that syntax is correct.

Thx!

Answer (score 10):

As diegows suggested, you can use iptables-restore, however you can use it with the --test flag to just test the configuration, rather than testing it as part of an actual installation.

```
iptables-restore --test [YOUR RULES AS A FILE]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to always work well.  I'm currently working on an iptables file that fails when actually installing it (iptables-restore < iptables-new) but with the --test option, no errors are generated.  I would post it but it is long.  m15440@NDC01P04CU2PNGA sysconfig # iptables-restore --test < iptables-new
m15440@NDC01P04CU2PNGA sysconfig # iptables-restore  < iptables-new
iptables-restore: line 217 failed
m15440@NDC01P04CU2PNGA sysconfig #

Answer (score 1):

Use iptables-save/iptables-restore. In my opinion, using script is a bad idea. Write your first rules from the command line, then save them with "iptables-save > file" and continue editing that file. "iptables-restore < file" is used to apply the rules. That command will check the syntax and won't apply the rules if there is an error.

Comment: Also, when playing with iptables on a remote machine, I also set up a cron job to run every 5 or 10 minutes that restores iptables to a default "allow all" state, so if I lock me self out, I'll back in within 5 to 10 minutes. Just remember to lock it down again and disable the cron job ;)